# HTC phones won't use given WifiConfiguration for a programatically created Hotspot in Android

Tags: android, wifi, wifimanager

I am working on an Android App which asks for SSID and Password from user to create a Hotspot. I am using the reflection method and WifiManager Class.

Everything works as expected on all phones but on the HTC Desire and HTC Explorer I have for testing the Access Point doesn't use the SSID and Password provided by me but it uses the SSID and Password which are setup in the Wi-fi Hotspot Application which is the default App by HTC.

Can someone please guide me with this, probably there is something which I am missing or something extra which I have to do in order to make the HTC phones use the settings given

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming questions. This is not a question. And, since you are not using documented and supported APIs, you should not be surprised when it does not work reliably.

Comment: I am sorry if this doesn't look like a programming question to you, but with all due respect I would like to state that this looks as much a programming question to me as any other question on Stack Overflow. And I used to think that stack overflow is for helping other programmers out. 
Anyways I am using a non supported API because I have no other choice, Android phones above 2.2 have the hotspot feature but no public API so we aren't left with anything else. I can't just make an app ICS when most of the world doesn't have ICS phones.

Comment: Questions in the English language involve the use of a question mark as punctuation. Please point out where in your "question" there is an actual English-language question. "because I have no other choice" -- you can not write the app.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I have edited the question. And yes I have no other choice and I couldn't find anyother solution by myself that is why I have posted it here before dropping the idea of writing this app, I hope you will understand that the knowledge I have on my own can't be all the knowledge and there may be someone in Stack Overflow who can help me with this and I can continue with the application again.

Comment: htc use its own way to store hotspot information. See my answer in  http://stackoverflow.com/a/15805686/249779